# AngularJS $http-service can not load UCS-2 JSON

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to load a UCS-2 JSON that looks like:

```
{
    "test": {
    }
}
```

I have setup the encoding in Notepadd++ (I have also tested it with Big Endian):
[image: Encoding in Notepad++]

So I am loading the JSON file with:

```
$http.get("myfile.json", {
    "cache": cache,
    "transformResponse": [function(data){
        console.log(data);
        return data;
    }]
}).then(function(response){
        if(typeof response.data === "object"){
            console.log("IT WORKED!");
            console.log(response.data);
        }
    }, function(err){
        console.error(err);
        throw(new Error("Can not load JSON"));
    }
);
```

When executing this I am getting the following in my console (because of transformResponse):
[image: Result in console]

When removing the transformResponse-element I am getting the actual angularjs error message:

> Error: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

What is wrong with my file? Why is angularjs not able to load and parse it?

I have tested the same with UTF-8 and it worked. But because my JSON should contain translations for about 6 languages it is necessary to have a character set that can contain all characters except those from asian and arabic languages.

Comment: default charset is utf-8. what are the content type headers being sent?

Comment: What I posted is everything I send.

Comment: However, even with ``Content-Type": "application/json;charset=utf-16"`` as a header it does not work